# Inverse of Euler's phi (totient) function

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

How do you calculate the inverse of Euler's totient function?

For example, what is $\phi^{-1}(12)$?

I'm confused as my lecture notes give no explanation, they just state that e.g. $\phi^{-1}(2)=-1$ and $\phi^{-1}(3)=-2$.

When I search for Inverse of Euler's totient function I get answers for how to solve $\phi(n)=k$, which is not what I'm looking for, so maybe I'm asking the wrong question?

I'm more confused by the fact the answer that I'm given is $\phi^{-1}(12)=2$ because if $\phi^{-1}(2)=-1$ and $\phi^{-1}(3)=-2$, assuming $\phi^{-1}$ is multiplicative, $\phi^{-1}(12)=(\phi^{-1}(2))^2\phi^{-1}(3)=(-1)^2(-2)=-2.$

Comment: The solutions to $\phi(n)=12$ are $13,21,26,28,36,42$. But if this is not what you mean by inverse, what do you mean?

Comment: Well, yes. They are equivalent problems to solve. If you know that $f(x)=y$ then we know that $f^{-1}(y)=x$. In your case, solving $\phi^{-1}(12)=x$ is equivalent to solving $\phi(x) =12$

Comment: Did you get your notes from a lecturer as part of a course? It would be best to ask that person for clarification.

Comment: See the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404116; with Julia implementation here https://github.com/anj1/AlgebraicNumbers.jl/blob/anj1_log_alg/src/inv_totient.jl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They meant the [Dirichlet inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution) of $\phi(n)$, which is a multiplicative function : $$gcd(n,m) = 1 \quad\implies\quad \phi(nm) = \phi(n)\phi(m)$$
From $\phi(p^k)= p^{k-1}(p-1)$ we obtain
$$\sum_{d | n} \phi(d) = n, \qquad \phi(n) = \sum_{d | n} \mu(d) \frac{n}{d}$$
where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function. thus
$$\phi^{-1}(n) =  \sum_{d | n} d \mu(d)$$
Which is multiplicative too. Therefore

$$\phi^{-1}(3) = 1-3 = -2, \qquad \phi^{-1}(2) = 1-2 = -1$$

$$\phi^{-1}(12) = \phi^{-1}(3)\phi^{-1}(4)= (1-3)(1-2) = 2$$

Comment: Excellent, thank you. That clears things up. Please could you clarify why $\phi^{-1}(12)= 2$ and not $-2$? I would have thought $\phi^{-1}(6)= 2$ but may be mistaken.

Comment: @math_apprentice I wrote how I get  $\phi^{-1}(12)=2$. It is not true that $\phi^{-1}(12) = \phi^{-1}(3) (\phi^{-1}(2))^2$ : $\phi^{-1}(n)$ is not completely multiplicative.